# Passing Firestore (v9) instance across packages

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, monorepo

I'm trying to write some Firestore operations into a separate package so that it could be imported and reused in different web apps. I'm building a **monorepo with different packages** and I'm trying to use **Firebase v9** for the following example:

From `packageA` I'm defining and exporting a `getPosts(db)` function that takes in a `Firestore` object and returns some posts form the given database

```
// in 'packageA'
import { collection, getDocs, Firestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

export const getPosts = async (db: Firestore) => {
  console.log('Passed in db: ', db); // This correctly prints the passed in Firestore object

  try {
    const postsCollection = collection(db, 'posts'); // This function will throw
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(postsCollection);

    return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error reading posts: ', e);
  }
}
```

In a web app I'm initialising the Firebase app and exporting the Firestore instance

```js
// firebase.js in 'web-app-1'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = { /* my Firebase config */ };

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Then I'm trying to use the `getPosts` function from the package in a component...

```js
// App.js in 'web-app-1'
import { db } from './firebase.js';
import { getPosts } from 'packageA';

let posts;

async function loadPosts() {
  try {
    posts = await getPosts(db);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

loadPosts(); // throws an error
```

but I get the following error from the `collection(db, 'posts')` call

> Error reading posts: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

even though the passed in database is correctly printed in the console (form the `getPosts` function)

**Note:** If I copy the whole `getPosts` function and use it directly in the web app (i.e. without importing it from another package) then it works and correctly fetches the posts.

Comment: Do you revamp it or use a code from Web version 8? There seem to be some compatibility issues/unexpected behavior when doing the migration and leaving some of the version 8 code

Comment: @FaridShumbar no this is a greenfield project with only version 9 of the Firebase SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking around a bit more and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70125720/10727584) to a similar question to solve my problem too.

Basically what I had to do is to specify Firebase as a `peerDependency` in `packageA` and **not include it in the final bundle**. The web apps that consume `packageA` will include Firebase as a regular `dependency`.

So the `package.json` files look as follows

In the utility package

```json
{
  "name": "packageA",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.3"
  }
}
```

and then in the web apps

```json
{
  "name": "web-app-1",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.3",
  }
}
```

This approach also makes sense to my use case as the web app – and only the web app – that initialises the Firebase app will include it in its bundle. I can imagine however that in some other use cases this is not a possible solution.

Nevertheless I have submitted my issue to the Firebase support as suggested and here is their answer:

> We have received some similar cases and we are already working to solve this. However, it can take a while due the workload of the engineering team, please, be patient.

Comment: if you import `firebase` as `peerDependencies`, how should I do if I actually need to import `firebase` other related functions for development. 

Currently I am facing a issue that in the so called `package-A` repo, the following error showed up. 

`Cannot find module 'firebase/firestore' or its corresponding type declarations`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug with version 9, and the method is trying to use a Firebase Realtime Database instead of Firestore, so the method is sending an error for the collections.

It seems to override the fact that it's Firestore when using the function, so I would send this to the [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) directly because the way that the package is being formed seems to be the main issue.

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor. I have submitted this issue for the Firebase support as suggested. Once they reply I will update here

Answer (score 0):

I am currently experience the same problem. The workaround is importing the files direct via the bundler.

Keep in mind this is not optimal because I have to install the packages in the native project again, so it requires some manual maintenance

## Project structure

- apps

  - native
  - web
- packages

  - utils

This ensures that my app uses the firebase instance and package that is inside `native/node_modules/`

## Metro.config.js

`

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");
const path = require("path");

const projectRoot = __dirname;
const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, "../..");

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

const extraNodeModules = {
  '@aim/utils': path.resolve(__dirname + '/../../packages/utils'),
};
const watchFolders = [
  path.resolve(__dirname + '/../../packages/utils')
];

config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot];
config.resolver.nodeModulesPath = [
  path.resolve(projectRoot, "node_modules"),
  path.resolve(workspaceRoot, "node_modules"),
];

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  }, 
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules: new Proxy(extraNodeModules, {
      get: (target, name) =>
        //redirects dependencies referenced from common/ to local node_modules
        name in target ? target[name] : path.join(process.cwd(), `node_modules/${name}`),
    }),
  },
  watchFolders,
};

// module.exports = config;
```

`

## getting types to work (native)

tsconfig.json
`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@aim/utils/*": ["../../packages/utils/*"]
    }
  },
}
```

`