# Monorepo shared common function for firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, next.js, monorepo

I have init a monorepo which has the following structure. Some of the functions from firebase need to be shared. Therefore I decide to put them in the package/utils repo. I need to pass down the firebase firestore or other firebase service instance to the functions in package/utils repo so that they can access to correct firebase project for different environment.

However, when I pass down the instance to the utils repo for 1 function which interact with firestore. I faced this **error** as described in another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606307/passing-firestore-v9-instance-across-packages). Therefore I used `peerDependencies` in my utils repo for firebase

But then when I go back to package/utils/src/index.ts, all of the functions from firebase doesn't work.

Wanna know if anyone has experience before and do u guys have some kind of direction on how to solve it. Thanks a lot!

```
monorepo/
  apps/
    web/
      - package.json
    react-native
      - package.json
  packages/
    utils/
      - package.json
      src/
        - index.ts
```

```
// in packages/util/package.json

{
  .....other attributes
  "peerDependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.3" //only here has 'firebase', not in the 'dependencies'
  }
}

//in web/package.json
{
  .....other attributes
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.3",
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Things I have tried to solve it:

1. run `yarn add firebase` -> The error above will happen again.
2. disable typescript checking -> still cannot compile

What I am expecting:

1. successfully passed down the firestore instance down to the function
2. Able to use firebase related library in package/utils/src/index.ts file